# Bind dojo dgrid to form with dojox.mvc

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I want to bind a dgrid to a form in dojo using dojox.mvc. While there are many samples on how to bind single models to forms there is nothing showing how to do this with a grid. 
The grid will have to share the same store with the form and when someone clicks a row in the grid the form will be updated.
My main problem is the difference in the stores they use: while dgrid uses dojo.store objects, mvc uses dojo.Stateful. dojo.store has an object named 'data' where it keeps the list of data while dojo.Stateful has 'items'. 
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not an expert of dgrid, I think bridging dgrid's selection and dojo/Stateful would help. Something like below (dgrid should be in the same directory as dojo/dijit/dojox, and /path/to/dojotoolkit should be replaced with the directory where dojo/dijit/dojox/dgrid are placed):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test dgrid and dojox/mvc</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <link id="themeStyles" rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            @import "/path/to/dojotoolkit/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
            h2 {
                margin: 12px;
            }
            .heading {
                font-weight: bold;
                padding-bottom: 0.25em;
            }
            .ui-widget{
                margin: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js" 
            data-dojo-config="async: true, mvc: {debugBindings: 1}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            require([
                "dojo/_base/declare",
                "dojo/_base/Color",
                "dojo/parser",
                "dojo/when",
                "dojo/Stateful",
                "dgrid/List",
                "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
                "dgrid/Selection",
                "dgrid/test/data/base",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], function(declare, Color, parser, when, Stateful, List, Grid, Selection){
                when(parser.parse(), function(){
                    var undef,
                        columns = {
                            col1: "Name",
                            col5: "Red",
                            col6: "Green",
                            col7: "Blue"
                        },
                        grid = new (declare([Grid, Selection]))({
                            store: smallColorStore,
                            columns: columns
                        }, "grid"),
                        Model = declare(Stateful, {
                            _colorGetter: function(){
                                return this.col5 === undef || this.col6 === undef || this.col7 === undef ? "" : new Color([this.col5, this.col6, this.col7]).toHex();
                            },
                            _colorSetter: function(value){
                                if(value){
                                    var rgb = new Color(value).toRgb();
                                    this.col5 = rgb[0];
                                    this.col6 = rgb[1];
                                    this.col7 = rgb[2];
                                }
                                return value;
                            }
                        });
                    grid.on("dgrid-select", function(event){
                        if((ctrl.model || {}).id !== undef && ctrl.model.id != event.rows[0].id){
                            save();
                        }
                        ctrl.set("model", new Model(event.rows[0].data));
                    });
                    grid.on("dgrid-deselect", function(event){
                        if((ctrl.model || {}).id !== undef && ctrl.model.id == event.rows[0].id){
                            save();
                            ctrl.set("model", new Model({col1: ""}));
                        }
                    });
                    function save(){
                        var model = ctrl.model;
                        if(model.id){
                            for(var s in columns){
                                grid.updateDirty(model.id, s, model[s]);
                            }
                        }
                        grid.save();
                    }
                    handleSaveButton = function(){
                        save();
                        grid.select(model.id);
                    };
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
        <h2>A basic grid with dojox/mvc</h2>
        <div id="grid"></div>
        <span data-dojo-id="ctrl"
         data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/ModelRefController"></span>
        <div style="padding:10px;"
         data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Group"
         data-dojo-props="target: at(ctrl, 'model')">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text"
             data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
             data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'col1')">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/ColorPalette"
             data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', 'color'), palette: '7x10'"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" style="margin:10px;"
         data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button"
         data-dojo-props="label: 'Save', onClick: function(){ handleSaveButton(); }">
    </body>
</html>
```